# AWS Glue - Getting partition information into a dynamic frame column

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue, partition

I am writing a Glue ETL job that takes an array of paths as an argument to create a DynamicFrame. The job will read data from the specified paths and create a DynamicFrame for further processing.

Having the following s3 folder structure:

```
s3://my_bucket/root/dt=2022-24-12/file.parquet
s3://my_bucket/root/dt=2022-25-12/file.parquet
s3://my_bucket/root/dt=2022-26-12/file.parquet ..
```

.

I've created a Glue job script using `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options` to load the data like so:

```
dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    format='parquet',
    connection_options={
        "paths": ["s3://my_bucket/root/"], # <---- provided as an argument
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)
```

which reads the DF correctly and produce the following DF:

| column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| data | data |
| data | data |

How can I add the partition data (dt) to the data frame, **without using a catalog DB** so the output would be:

| column_A | Column_B | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | 2022-24-12 |
| data | data | 2022-24-12 |

I.E all data from a specific partition would get the correct date